# HTML/PHP form wont submit in Safari

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, safari, submit

The below HTML and PHP code executes as expected in Google Chrome - enter the requested data into the form and press send, then a message is sent to an email address and the page is refreshed.

However, the same expected behaviour does not occur in Safari - once the 'send' button is clicked the user is brought to a blank white page (the email.php file).

Can anyone tell me why it does not do as expected in Safari?

HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" id="contactForm" name="contactForm" class="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate" action="email.php" onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">

                      <div class="row">

                        <!-- Name Input -->
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="contact-text">Name:</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 contact-col">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Email Input -->
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="contact-text">Email:</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 contact-col">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Message Input -->
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="contact-text">Message:</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 contact-col">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8 text-end">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    <div class="submitting"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
$errors = [];
  $errorMessage = '';

  if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      if (empty($name)) {
          $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
      }

      if (empty($email)) {
          $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
      } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
      }

      if (empty($message)) {
          $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
      }

      if (empty($errors)) {
          $toEmail = 'cillinlyons@outlook.com';
          $emailSubject = 'New email from your contant form';
          $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'];

          $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message];
          $body = join('<br>', $bodyParagraphs);

          if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
              header('Location: https://cillinlyons.me');
          } else {
              $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
          }
      } else {
          $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
          $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
      }
  }

?>
```

Comment: `onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"` What do those functions do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a name for your button to set it with php
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Send</button>`
and use array_push() to have all errors in a array ,
i used isset() for check the submit is clicked or not.

```
 <?php

$errors = [];
$errorMessage = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Name is empty');
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Email is empty');
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Email is invalid');
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Message is empty');
    }



if (empty($errors)) {
    $toEmail = 'cillinlyons@outlook.com';
    $emailSubject = 'New email from your contant form';
    $headers = ['From' => $email, 'Reply-To' => $email, 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'];

    $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", $message];
    $body = join('<br>', $bodyParagraphs);

    if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) {
        header('Location: https://cillinlyons.me');
    } else {
        $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later';
    }
} else {
        foreach ($errors as $error)
            echo "<p style='color: red;'>{$error}</p>";
}}
```

i tested this on safari and its working